# Trying to implement predictRaw() for classification model in Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, matrix-multiplication

The developer API example (https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/ml/DeveloperApiExample.scala) gives a simple implementation example for the function predictRaw() in a classification model. This is a function within abstract class ClassificationModel that must be implemented in the concrete class. According to the developer API example, you can calculate it as follows:

```
override def predictRaw(features: Features.Type): Vector = {
  val margin = BLAS.dot(features, coefficients)
  Vectors.dense(-margin, margin) // Binary classification so we return a length-2 vector, where index i corresponds to class i (i = 0, 1).
}
```

My understanding of `BLAS.dot(features, coefficients)` is that this is simply the matrix dot product of the features vector (of length numFeatures) by the coefficients vector (of length numFeatures), so effectively each 'feature' cols is mutliplied by a coefficient and then summed to get `val margin`. However Spark no longer provides access to the BLAS library as it's private in MLlib and instead matrix mutliplication is provided in the Matrix trait where there are various factory methods for multiplication.

My understanding of how to implement `predictRaw()` using the matrix factory methods is as follows:

```
override def predictRaw(features: Vector): Vector = {

//coefficients is a Vector of length numFeatures: val coefficients = Vectors.zeros(numFeatures)
val coefficientsArray = coefficients.toArray
val coefficientsMatrix: SparkDenseMatrix = new SparkDenseMatrix(numFeatures, 1, coefficientsArray)
val margin: Array[Double] = coefficientsMatrix.multiply(features).toArray // contains a single element
val rawPredictions: Array[Double] = Array(-margin(0),margin(0))
new SparkDenseVector(rawPredictions)
}
```

This will require the overhead of converting the data structures to Arrays. Is there a better way? It seems strange that BLAS is now private. NB. Code not tested! At the moment `val coefficients: Vector` is just a vector of zeros, but once I have implemented the learning algorithm this would contain the results.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have worked this out. The Spark DeveloperAPI example is very confusing because predictRaw() computes a confidence interval for a logistic-regression type example. However what predictRaw() is actually supposed to do, when implementing ClassificationModel, is predict a vector of output labels for every ith sample of the input dataset. Technically speaking the matrix multiplication above is correct without the use of BLAS - but in fact predictRaw() doesn't have to be calculated this way.

From the underlying source code: 
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.2.0/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/classification/Classifier.scala

`* @return  vector where element i is the raw prediction for label i.
   *          This raw prediction may be any real number, where a larger value indicates greater
   *          confidence for that label.`

The function raw2predict then computes the actual label from the raw prediction but doesn't need to be implemented as this is done by the API.